# Custom build of openSSL for OS X - limit ciphers suites

Tags: c, macos, configuration, openssl

### Main goal

I need openSSL. Apple deprecated this library since 10.7 It is even impossible to create context when ignoring warnings about deprecation.

I decided to build openSSL and tweak it to my needs:

- disable SSL protocol (only TLS should be supported)
- limit cipher suites to secure one

### What I have done

How I'm trying to build it.
I've [downloaded sources](https://www.openssl.org/source/) version `1.0.2d` and configured it this way:

```bash
./Configure -openssldir=$(pwd)/output-build \
    enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 \
    no-ssl2 no-ssl3 \
    no-shared no-comp \
    enable-TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA \
    enable-TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA \
    enable-TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA \
    enable-TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA \
    enable-TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA \
    enable-TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA \
    enable-TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA \
    enable-TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA \
    enable-TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA \
    enable-TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA \
    enable-TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA \
    enable-TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA \
    darwin64-x86_64-cc
```

### Problem

Switches for disabling SSL are clear and I'm happy with it.
Switches for cipher suites are very inconvenient, I'm not sure how they work. They are not documented, `./Configure --help` prints this:

> Usage: Configure [**no-**<**cipher**> ...] [**enable-**<**cipher**> ...]
>   [**experimental-**<**cipher**> ...] [-Dxxx] [-lxxx] [-Lxxx] [-fxxx] [-Kxxx]
>   [no-hw-xxx|no-hw] [[no-]threads] [[no-]shared]
>   [[no-]zlib|zlib-dynamic] [no-asm] [no-dso] [no-krb5] [sctp] [386]
>   [--prefix=DIR] [--openssldir=OPENSSLDIR] [--with-xxx[=vvv]]
>   [--test-sanity] os/compiler[:flags]

I just want listed cipher suites and nothing else. Format of this switches give me impression that I have to disable [quite long list of other cipher suites](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/ciphers.html). Is there better way so I can disabled all but those listed above?

Comment: Why not just install Macports and do `sudo port install openssl`?  There is no need to disable anything as it will just pull in what is used, during linking.

Comment: this way I will tighten security iin whole application, also in code which I'm not modifying. `Macports` will give me everything also parts I want get rid off.

Comment: Tighten security on what way?

Comment: See configuration and question. SSL is removed (not secure enough) and question is to disable (remove) cipher suites which my client consider as not strong enough.

Comment: Disable some features on build level of `openSSL` will make application resistant to careless developers. This will standardize security level without enforcing on other developers some code patterns,